# Simple C++ Dynamicly allocated Matrix with only one memory allocation

Tags: c++, matrix, memory-management, memory-optimization

I was bothered with existing matrix allocation methods that take variable rows and columns, so I made a small class that only needs one memory allocation.

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Matrix{
    T* data;
    size_t rows, columns;

public:
    Matrix(const size_t rows, const size_t columns) : rows(rows), columns(columns) {
        // One single allocation to store data
        data = new T[rows+columns + 1];
    }

    T* operator[](const size_t r) {
        return data+(r*columns);
    }
};

// Example

int main() {

    Matrix<int> mat(5,3);

    mat[2][1] = 1;

    //...

}
```

Comment: What aspects do you expect reviewers to go over?

Comment: Lot missing from this. Have a look at my article on vectors. You should be able to apply the same principles to Matrix allocation. https://lokiastari.com/series/ You may also need to read up on how to overload `operator[]` for 2 dimensional array accesses https://stackoverflow.com/a/1971207/14065

Comment: @MartinYork Very nice article on your website, ill surely learn a lot from it.

Comment: Then there's the out-of-bounds memory access (caused because the memory allocated in the constructor is the wrong amount).

Answer (score 2):

- Since you have the `new` keyword, you should make a destructor and `delete[]`.

```cpp
~Matrix()
{
    delete[] data;
    data = nullptr;
}
```

Note that it is not necessary to set `data = nullptr` in the destructor, because it will be deleted as soon as the destructor is called.

- You are missing a [**copy constructor**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) which can cause problems when assigning one matrix to another
- What happens if the number passed in `[]` when slicing from the matrix is out of bounds?
- Have a glance at [**std::initialzer_list**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) in C++, it will simplify assigning values to the matrix.
- You will have to overload the arithmetic operators ( `+, -, *, /`) if you want to perform any kind of operations between two matrices
- Lastly, I was a little confused to see `size_t` rather than `std::size_t`, if you have `using std::size_t` in your source code, you should have it here too to avoid confusion.

Comment: You're correct about the need for a destructor, copy constructor and so on, but these things can all be avoided by using `std::vector<T> data`.

Comment: When you see something like this in the code `//...` it is better not to answer and flag it for community attention because the question is off-topic, missing review context.

Comment: I agree with you people but maybe he missed his " reinventing the wheel tag " right?

Comment: @MartinYork I wasn't aware of this, can you link any site where I can read about it? I have removed that para so I hope its fine now

Comment: @AryanParekh: You can read a bunch of my code reviews here. :-)

Comment: @MartinYork I'm not sure what you mean xD, I did read about variable shadowing, but isn't `rows(rows)` confusing? `this` makes it specific right?

Comment: In the **initializer list**: `rows(rows)` is very standard pattern. Both parameter and member are easily distinguishable and so easy to read (In the initializer list). So this is a common pattern. Your constructor parameters tend to have the same name as the variable they are initializing. Also you can not use `this` in the initializer list so that is a mute point.

Comment: Outside the initializer list. Using `this->x = something;` is bad practice. The problem here is that the only reason to use `this->` is because you have shadowed variable `x` and thus need to explicitly distinguish it. The problem comes when you accidentally forget to put the `this->` on the variable. The compiler can not tell if this was a mistake or not and for somebody else reading your code it will also to be hard to tell which `x` the original coder was referring to.

Comment: The solution is not to add `this->` (because some places it is supposed to be there and others not and you can not distinguish between the two), Rather your variables names should be distinct and unique so that you never need to use `this->` in the first place.

Comment: @MartinYork perfect explanation, sorry for that since I'm always learning new stuff every day, the stack exchange network has become my second teacher.

Comment: Why do you have `data = nullptr` in your code, then follow up by saying that it is unnecessary? Just leave it out.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes it is unnecessary but I mentioned it otherwise since this isn't always the case, and you might forget to set the `data = NULL`, which can be dangerous, I thought it would have been useful to OP if I mentioned it